# Mongoose findOne converting the Array type field in object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have been building a chat application,and I am storing user with a schema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
email: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
},
username: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
},
contacts: {
 type: ContactSchema,
},
});
```

and ContactSchema as

```
const ContactSchema = new Schema({
 contactUserId: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
},
});
```

the problem is that, when I try to find the user in mongo shell with findOne, It retrieves the user with contacts array:

```
{
 "_id" : "49Ff7aRn4baPuTVFefQLulbMIeE2",
 "username" : "john",
 "email" : "doe@gmail.com",
 "__v" : 0,
 "contacts" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb07958b0315c6303505f74"),
        "contactUserId" : "RHOCbyCtvjQfFzFukxiwS9wV1ly1"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb07e4eff338702ba455c8a"),
        "contactUserId" : "tGCkdHh55UgkG8AW0Ab6S9guwcF3"
    }
 ]
```

}

but when I try to use mongoose findOne, It retrieves the user with contacts field as an object:

```
{ _id: '49Ff7aRn4baPuTVFefQLulbMIeE2',
 username: 'john',
 email: 'doe@gmail.com',
 __v: 0,
 contacts:
  { '0':
     { _id: 5eb07958b0315c6303505f74,
       contactUserId: 'RHOCbyCtvjQfFzFukxiwS9wV1ly1' },
    '1':
     { _id: 5eb07e4eff338702ba455c8a,
       contactUserId: 'tGCkdHh55UgkG8AW0Ab6S9guwcF3' },
    _id: 5eb086555cbcb03801350d76 } }
```

Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of your mongoose `UserSchema` :

Change `contacts: { type: ContactSchema }` of type Object to `contacts: [ContactSchema]` of type array of Objects as like below :

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  contacts: [ContactSchema],
});
```

On mongo shell, As you don't have any conversion so it's pretty simple & returns the document from DB as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
email: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
},
username: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
},
contacts: [ContactSchema]
});
```

contacts should  be mentioned as above instead of

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
email: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
},
username: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
},
contacts: {
 type: ContactSchema,
},
});
```